# How to Read value of any node element from XML formatted string?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, web-services

I have following `XML` formatted string in `string __MessageIn` variable:

```
string _MessageIn=
    <?Label TSRAY|RESERVATION|317859|SUCCESS?>
    <Reservation xmlns="reservation.fidelio.2.0" mfShareAction="NA" mfReservationAction="EDIT">
      <HotelReference>
        <hotelCode>TSRAY</hotelCode>
      </HotelReference>
      <confirmationID>Y6Z7TFJDK</confirmationID>
      <reservationID>347557</reservationID>
      <reservationOriginatorCode>JA</reservationOriginatorCode>
      <originalBookingDate>2010-08-16T22:53:23.000</originalBookingDate>
      <StayDateRange timeUnitType="DAY">
        <startTime>2010-08-19T00:00:00.000</startTime>
        <numberOfTimeUnits>3</numberOfTimeUnits>
      </StayDateRange>
      <GuestCounts>
        <GuestCount>
          <ageQualifyingCode>ADULT</ageQualifyingCode>
          <mfCount>2</mfCount>
        </GuestCount>
        <GuestCount>
          <ageQualifyingCode>CHILD</ageQualifyingCode>
          <mfCount>0</mfCount>
        </GuestCount>
      </GuestCounts>
      ...................
     ..................
    </Reservation>
```

I'm trying to get the value of hotelcode i.e. **TSRAY**   from `<hotelCode>TSRAY</hotelCode>` but the code always returns `NULL` In `HotelReference`.

**I tried below lines of code:**

```
// query the XML document
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_MessageIn);

var HotelReference = doc.Descendants("HotelReference").Select(x => new { HotelCode = x.Element("hotelCode").Value}).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I get the required value from above `XML` formatted `string variable`?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of namespaces being part of the xml.

There are 2 ways to overcome this issue, either remove the namespace "reservation.fidelio.2.0" then your code will work without issues. But this might not be feasable.

So we'll have to pass the namespace along with the nodenames when performing searches.. try the following and this would solve your issue. Hope this helps.

```
        string ns = "reservation.fidelio.2.0";
        string node = "HotelReference";
        string elem = "hotelCode";
        XName xn = XName.Get(node, ns);
        XName xe = XName.Get(elem, ns);
        var HotelReference = doc.Root.Descendants(xn).Select(x => new { HotelCode = x.Element(xe).Value }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 string _MessageIn="<?Label TSRAY|RESERVATION|317859|SUCCESS?>    <Reservation xmlns='reservation.fidelio.2.0' mfShareAction='NA' mfReservationAction='EDIT'>      <HotelReference>        <hotelCode>TSRAY</hotelCode>      </HotelReference>     <confirmationID>Y6Z7TFJDK</confirmationID>      <reservationID>347557</reservationID>      <reservationOriginatorCode>JA</reservationOriginatorCode>      <originalBookingDate>2010-08-16T22:53:23.000</originalBookingDate>      <StayDateRange timeUnitType='DAY'>        <startTime>2010-08-19T00:00:00.000</startTime>        <numberOfTimeUnits>3</numberOfTimeUnits>      </StayDateRange>      <GuestCounts>        <GuestCount>          <ageQualifyingCode>ADULT</ageQualifyingCode>          <mfCount>2</mfCount>        </GuestCount>        <GuestCount>          <ageQualifyingCode>CHILD</ageQualifyingCode>          <mfCount>0</mfCount>        </GuestCount>      </GuestCounts>      ...................   ..................    </Reservation>";    
                string HotelCode = ""; // you can create HotelCode-Array to store all Hotelcodes
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(_MessageIn);
                XmlNodeList list=doc.GetElementsByTagName("hotelCode");
                foreach (XmlNode node in list)
                {
                    if (node.Name == "hotelCode")
                    {
                        HotelCode=node.InnerText;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sidestepping the namespaces like this only works on small and restricted cases. The use of the older XmlDocument may or may not be acceptable.